# Redux Toolkit with server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, redux-toolkit

How to get the benefits of server side rendering when using redux toolkit? I tried to dispatch thunks in getserversideprops, it is not supporting it. For that I made an API call directly in getserversideprops which gives list of users, adding and deleting users I managed in client side rendering, here comes the problem, on adding/deleting user data on the screen is not getting updated till the reload of the current page. I searched in stackoverflow and found this answer
`const refreshData = () => { router.replace(router.asPath); }`
But it didn't work for me. Is there a way to refresh the data from the getserversideprops on some action is happended in the jsx?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.